# How to retrieve content from XML file using PHP - YouTube API

Tags: php, xml, youtube-api

Please help in using PHP and XML in retrieving dynamic content.

I have this code:

```
function yt_name() {
$xmlData = file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/youtube/uploads?max-results=5&prettyprint=true' ); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData); 
$yt_name = $xml->event->name;

    echo $yt_name;

}
```

How can I retrieve the content inside `<name>content</name>` ?

Regards,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once inside the object, you can retrieve childs by object index (node name):

```
function yt_name() {
    $xmlData = file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/youtube/uploads?max-results=5&prettyprint=true' ); 
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData); 
    return $xml;
}

$yt = yt_name();
echo $yt->author->name;
```

Output: **YouTube Spotlight**

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this anymore V2 API is deprecated since april 2014 and will be closed on 21 april 2015

Use the json V3 API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Thanks for the alert man!! will then switch to V3 and JSON.. oh bother, SimpleXML was nice and easy :'(
Appreciated, I wasn't aware of such thing !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your XML format looks like, but something like this should work -

```
$XMLData =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<video>
<name>This is the name</name>
<submitter>Mrs. Robinson</submitter>
</video>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($XMLData) or die("Error");


echo $xml->name;
```